# Find length of variable in the template class

Tags: c++, templates, size, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy

Consider the method below:

```
template <class T>
void Entry<T>::setValue(T * value) {
  int size = ?;
  this->key = new T();
  memcpy(this->value, value, size);
}
```

How I could find the length for `value`? If it was a `char*` i could use something like that: `strlen(value)`, but it is not. What the alternstive here?

I try use this:

```
template <class T>
void Entry<T>::setValue(T * value) {
  this->value = value;
}
```

but the value was staying empty after the method call.

**UPDATE**

I have tried this, but do not compile:

```
template <class T>
void Entry<T>::setValue(T * value) {
  int size = sizeof(value)/sizeof(value[0]);
  cout << "size = " << size << endl;
  this->key = new T();
  memcpy(this->value, value, size);
}
```

the error is:

```
Entry.cpp:35:13: error: cannot convert ‘JSON_Value*’ to ‘char*’ in assignment
   this->key = new T()
```

**UPDATE 2**

Another try, this time the code compiles but the execution gives me a Segmentation fault in the second line:

```
template <class T>
void Entry<T>::setValue(T * value) {
  T temp = *value;
  *value = *this->value;
  *this->value = temp;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(T)` but it seems you are after something else, given your comment about `strlen`, which does *not* give the size of a `char*`.

Comment: By size do you mean length, or size in bytes? Since you are using `memcpy`, I would believe you need the `sizeof` operator

Comment: more like length, I mean. `sizeof` do not return what I want ( I already try that).

Comment: @juanchopanza the answer to the other question you suggested do not solve the current problem (see the update I added).

Comment: It tells you why what you're trying can't possibly work.

Comment: What the alternative then? How I could assign a value to a member of a template class?

Comment: You cannot get lenght of dynamically allocated array just from pointer. Btw, sizeof(value)/sizeof(value[0]) is pretty much random value as sizeof(value) will evaluate to 4 or 8 (on 32 or 64 bit system) and sizeof(value[0]) into sizeof(T)

Comment: @R2RT Is there a way to assign a value to the member variable of a template class in that particular case? This class have another attribute, but as its type was `char* ` was easy figure out how to do this assignment.

Comment: Something like this? This is basic example, it would be better to make some more template magic with static_assert and type traits. https://repl.it/KgF0/0